# how to enforce ddd aggregates in java or c#?

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design

Evans writes that the concept of an aggregate is such that all of the objects of an aggregate that aren't the root must not be referenced by any other object that isn't it's aggregate root.
Are there any reasonable ways to enforce this in Java or C#. That is, if I introduce an Aggregate in a code base, can I ensure that no developer in the future who is not so interested in DDD will create a reference directly to a sub part from outside the aggregate? Or at least make it hard for him/her to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way that will not excessively restrict the usability of your entities or add complexity that will outweigh the benefits. You should keep in mind that having a transient (temporary) reference to a non-root entity is legit and can be useful in certain circumstances, so static scope-based restrictions are not really an option.

When it comes to high-level design principles, I tend to prefer relying on team culture and developer guidelines over defensive programming, because the latter generally backfires in some way and you'll end up with ugly overcomplicated code to allow exceptions to the rigid barriers you set yourself. "Architectural" frameworks kind of fall into the same category -- straightforward and productive for simple applications but when you start adding exception cases, they soon become a burden more than a help.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your Aggregate's content is not reachable from outside, you have to compose it (add content) through its root only. You have to store deep copies of what is provided from outside in order to avoid storing already referenced objects. In other words, you must only store objects created by the root itself. The same applies to returning Aggregate content to outer world - the root must only return deep copies of the stored objects, thus protecting them from being referenced.

Since we talk about referencing, it makes sense to also copy immutable objects, thus controlling when they become eligible for Garbage Collection (Java).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this is not my understanding of ddd Aggregates. I think the idea is that a subpart of an Aggregate should be referenced only by going through the root. And when an external object has access to it this way it should be transient. Deep copies are not a solution because it's not a good idea to make copies indiscriminately of entities. I also don't think object copies are a solution since the focus is on the conceptual object, not the object instance, i.e. an instance copy of an entity  is still the same conceptual object since its id will be copied as well.